# Can't install blackfire-php package via APT package manager

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt, blackfire

I get an error when trying to install `blackfire-php` with command `sudo apt-get install blackfire-php` on my Ubuntu Desktop 15.10.
There's a full stack output in console:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  blackfire-php
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/930 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2 552 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package blackfire-php.
(Reading database ... 363177 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../blackfire-php_1.8.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking blackfire-php (1.8.0) ...
Setting up blackfire-php (1.8.0) ...

We are sorry but we were unable to find any suitable version of Blackfire Probe for your system.
We would like to help you, please contact us on https://blackfire.io using the Feedback button.
OS: Linux victor-desktop 4.2.0-25-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 12:31:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Architecture: amd64
PHP ABI version(s) detected: 20131226
PHP extension directory: rh-based

dpkg: error processing package blackfire-php (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 blackfire-php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anybody help with it?

Comment: `We are sorry but we were unable to find any suitable version of Blackfire Probe for your system.
We would like to help you, please contact us on https://blackfire.io using the Feedback button.` This is the key message in your log. Do what it says.

Comment: Thanks @CharlotteDunois! I just wondering is there a method to see why it failed exactly? I mean some verbose information etc.

Comment: It failed because there is no version for your system available, that's all.